# MYSQL Full Text Search with keyword has space to match the column with name has no space

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I've an trouble when using full text search keyword has space to match the column with name has no space. Ex: The column name is `StackOverFlow`, the keyword is `Stack Over Flow`, I tried to using this query but didn't work:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST('%Stack%Over%Flow%').
```

Can anyone help to from this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't do it like this. You'll need to remove spaces in `php` or create some kind of a mapping dictionary for similar search terms.